# How to give wheel radius in ros_stage?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We want to design a robot in stage.
Here are the required specifications:
wheel radius=15 cm
distance between two wheels = 40 cm
how these can be added in the design?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199288/how-to-give-wheel-radius-in-ros_stage?/) by [robospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/18911/robospace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Stage does not simulate robot motion on this physical level. You probably want to use Gazebo instead, if you want to physically simulate your robot. In Stage a robot simply has a velocity and direction where it moves to following a given command.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2014-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0